# Acquiring a tourist visa for Uruguay in Germany for a non-German traveller

Tags: indian-citizens, tourist-visas, german-residents, uruguay

I am an Indian living and working in Germany. I wish to travel to Uruguay in late 2018.

According to [WikiTravel Page for Uruguay](https://wikitravel.org/en/Uruguay):

> Citizens of India have to apply for tourist visas but this visa is free of charge.

On the contrary, when I checked out the Embassy Details on [this particular website](https://www.embassy-worldwide.com/embassy/consulate-of-uruguay-in-bremen-germany/), it states the following:

> Uruguayan passport and visa from are issued only to citizens whose main residence is in Uruguay and Germany.

I have been living in Germany for more than 4 years now and wish to apply for a visa to Uruguay. I checked the [Uruguayan Consulate in Hamburg's Website](http://conuruale.de/k2.html), which apparently only mentions countries which do not require visas.

Am I really eligible to get one in Germany or do I have to apply for one in India?

Comment: Your residence is in Germany; why wouldn't you be able to get a visa in Germany?

Comment: it states main residence. I work here and _officially_ my status is temporary resident.

Comment: You have to be resident to qualify, not permanently resident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says

> Staatsbürger von Ländern, die nicht auf der Liste stehen, sind visumpflichtig. Um die benötigten Unterlagen für einen Visumantrag zu erfahren, setzen Sie sich bitte mit dem für Sie zuständigen Konsulat in Verbindung ([Antrag auf Erteilung eines Visums für die Einreise in Uruguay](http://conuruale.de/SOLICITUD%20DE%20VISA%20%28ale%29.pdf)).

Citizens of countries which are not on the list require a visa. To learn about the necessary documents for a visa application, please contact the appropriate consulate (Application Form for the grant of a visa to enter Uruguay).

One of the fields in the form is

> Bindung mit Deutschland (z.B. Daueraufenthalstgenehmigung)
> [sic]

So they want to know why Hamburg would be appropriate, and your Aufenthaltstitel is a reason to apply there.